How to use the nvidia container toolkit with prebuilt docker binaries?
For now, I install the docker by directly download the prebuilt binaries tar file and use as the user root. By using ./dockerd --config-file path/to/daemon.json to launch the docker service, how am I supposed to use nvidia driver in my container? The nvidia container toolkit seems to funciton by modifying the docker config file in /etc/docker , stated in the documentation, but the path to my daemon.json is specified manually and not in the /etc/docker directory.
As I am working on the public shared machine, I would prefer to do dependency compiling and experiments in a ubuntu docker image, thus won't change libraries already exist on the host, as I can't guarantee dependencies by apt install won't break others' experiment environments.
